# class path for jars within jars

Tags: java, jar, classpath, manifest

I have one application , where I am using one jar called "**A**" which internally refers to classes from another jar called "**B**", where jar "**B**" refers to classes from jar "**C**".

how to execute java application while setting class path to A.jar and add classpath dependency of B.jar and C.jar in manifest file of A.jar.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can set Class path in MENIFEST.MF file of A.jar like this

```
Class-Path : dependency/B.jar dependency/C.jar
```

where dependency is the folder which contains B and C jars

Answer (score 0):

You can specify classes to include in the Class-Path header field in the manifest file of an applet or application (A.jar in your case). The Class-Path header takes the following form:

```
Class-Path: jar1-name jar2-name directory-name/jar3-name
```

Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html